# Text overlapping with CSS transform property

Tags: html, css, html-table, transform, right-align

When I am using

```
 .right-align {
     text-align: right !important;
     transform: translateX(-40%);
 }
```

> The Table structure is showing below

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Bid
            </th>
            <th>Offer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="right-align">
                    200
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="right-align">
                    221
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The td is overlapping the th element as seen below

[image: Text overlap image]

How can I can make it go under the header ?

This is happening when table is scrolling

Comment: add new row value with <tr> element. please refer this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Please show a proper table structure

Comment: The code you have given does not demonstrate the problem. Please turn it into a runnable snippet and add whatever else there is in your system that is altering the layout that way. If you are unsure what CSS is being applied, use your browser devtools to look at the CSS on a right-align cell.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer the question as it is, however, the table should keep its proportions and structure as long as you keep the code tight:

```css
.right-align {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Bid</th>
      <th>Offer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="right-align">200</td>
      <td class="right-align">221</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It is nebulous why you decided to use the `transform: translateX(-40%);` rule in there, but it seems you may be trying to overwrite some rules that come from a theme hence the problem you are facing; If you update your question and add more pieces of code or at least what you are trying to achieve then i could be more helpful :). Also if you are using a framework or theme specify which one.

EDIT.
I saw your updates, you don't need to add a div within the td element to apply a class, you can do it directly in the td element. However, it seems that some css rules are overlapping. Maybe a screenshot of the results in a browser could be helpful.

Comment: I am using translate function to move the content towards left because text align right is pushing it towards extreme left

Comment: Without the translate function it is working fine, and going below the header when I am scrolling,

Comment: In that case you could use padding instead of transform to keep the structure of the table intact and avoid overlapping.